# KeyAuth and Python License Expiry

Tags: python, authentication, licensing

Has anyone been able to use KeyAuth and Python to check a license key to see if its in date i have tried the documents and my own code below but can not get it to work. I get the answer successful even if the key has expired however the if statement does not work at all.

```
def getchecksum():
    md5_hash = hashlib.md5()
    file = open(''.join(sys.argv), "rb")
    md5_hash.update(file.read())
    digest = md5_hash.hexdigest()
    return digest


keyauthapp = api(
    name = "MYNAME",
    ownerid = "MOWNERID",
    secret = "MYSECRETCODE",
    version = "1.0",
    hash_to_check = getchecksum()
)


def answer():
    key = input('Enter your license: ')
    keyauthapp.license(key)
    e = keyauthapp.license(key)

    if e is not True:
      # run function
    else:
      print("key invalid")
```

answer()`

i have tried also

```
if answer() == sucessfully logged in:
```

this also does not work

Comment: I believe you wanted the if statement inside the answer function??

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `if e is not True:` to: `if e is not None:`.

Alternatively, if you want to check sub expiry time:

```
print("subscription expires at: " + datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(keyauthapp.user_data.expires)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Remember to import datetime as: `from datetime import datetime`